# Promise internal working

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious to know if javascript promise uses callback internally. Is it a specification to avoid pyramid of doom and make the code neat? (It internally does the callback stuff?)

Comment: i think it depends on the browser. why it matters?

Comment: `var myPromise = function() {
  return {
    then: function(handler) {
      var data = 100;
      handler(data);
    }
  };
}`... [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4dqkzzaa/)

Comment: I think you are talking about something that is known as "callback hell". This is one of my favorite articles on promises and it talks exactly about this aspect of promises: https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it uses "callbacks" in the sense that it calls a function passed in to `.then(callback)`, but a promise is much more than a callback. It

- handles exceptions and reject "reason" with the `onRejected` part of `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`
- is chainable, ie `.then().then().then()...` which makes the "callbacks" very composable

Everything you can do with a promise, you can also do with a callback, but promises are indeed sometimes easier to read, maintain, and happen to avoid the "pyramid of doom" as you mentioned.

Comment: A good example abouit the chainable promise is about having one layer receiving data from the server and reformatting them and the 2nd layer using already formatted data. This bring a separation of concerns and is really easy to implements

Comment: @kavun This is like how we can make an ajax easier in jquery without writing lot of code by creating xmlhttpreq object and so on in js.  To get a modular , easily manageable code. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and thanks for the info !!

Comment: You can use callbacks instead of jqXHR (implements a promise interface) if you use the `success` callback option on `$.ajax`, so either way it's better than raw `XMLHttpRequest`